# Interpreting a statement regarding Determinants.

Tags: matrices, determinant

Let A be any matrix. Let S be any set of rows of A. What does the statement "each minor determinant in S which has as many rows as S" mean?

Doesn't minor determinant of S has necessarily lesser rows than S or am I missing something obvious?

I am reading INTEGRAL BOUNDARY POINTS OF CONVEX POLYHEDRA by Kruksal and Hoffman, and I found the above statement there. Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: I suspect it means a $k \times k$-minor of $A$ using the rows from $S$, where $k = \left|S\right|$.

Comment: Seems to make a lot of sense